Why Can't I Do This Animation Correctly?
The video of what I'm talking about



First of all what I want to happen is that the cube approces the ball, kicks it, the ball hit him in the head and he falls down but on the way he starts the fall down I don't know why. The keyframe on the 1 is where he begins, the keyframe on the 70 when he reaches the the place where he hit the ball, the keyframe on the 115 is the same one as 70 nothing changes but I don't know why I don't have the orange line between (using blender 4.1) and the keyframe after 115 is actually where he needs to starts to fall down but it actually begins before that keyframe so can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Open a Dopesheet window, select the animated Empty and expand its animation channels, identifiy which is the channel responsible for the wrong rotation (Euler X Rot, in my example), select its keyframe at frame 1, press Shift D to duplicate it and move the duplicate to frame 115.

